# getRunningAppProcesses() does not return launcher package("com.android.launcher") in Lollipop 5.1.1

Tags: android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am using the below code for getting current processes running on top. But it did not return  launcher package("com.android.launcher") when i am in home screen of the device.

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) this
            .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager
            .getRunningAppProcesses();
for (RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes) {

        if ((process.pkgList[0].equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.launcher"))
                || (process.pkgList[0]
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox"))
                )) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: i have same problem it returns only my app package name instead of launcher package name.